# Oracle nvarchar2(4000) column wont be imported into SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-server-2008-r2, openquery

I am trying to run this on SQL Server 2008 R2.

```
SELECT * FROM 
OPENQUERY(linked_oracle_server, 'SELECT A.Column1, A.Column2 from A')
```

This used to work before. We started facing the problem when the `A.Column1` was altered to `nvarchar2(4000)` on the Oracle side.

Now it fails with the following error:

> Cannot create a column accessor for OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle"
>   for "linked_oracle_server"

I was playing around a bit, if I do `SUBSTR(A.Column1,1,2000)` it works! And if I change it to `SUBSTR(A.Column1,1,2001)` it gives the same error as above. Does this have to do with `NVARCHAR` having a maximum limit of 4000 on the SQL Server side? Is there no way to import an Oracle column of size greater then `NVARCHAR2(2000)`, even though `NVARCHAR(MAX)` is capable of supporting much bigger data on SQL Server?

Comment: Please run this query: `select table_name, column_name, data_length, char_col_decl_length, char_used
from all_tab_columns
where table_name = 'TABLENAME' 
and column_name = 'COLUMN1'
;` where `TABLENAME` is the name of the table, and `COLUMN` is the name of this column, and paste results to the question.

Comment: That doesn't seem likely, SQL Server can definitely handle nvarchar columns longer than 2000 characters.  I did find this seemingly related bug: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9ede558a-9ac5-4c61-97ed-f8f52c7f8f44/msg-7340-level-16-state-4-line-1-cannot-create-a-column-accessor-for-ole-db-provider-ibmdasql?forum=sqldatabaseengine.  The other thing you might want to try is isolating the problem.  So just make a table in Oracle with a single `nvarchar2(4000)` column and try to select from that.

Comment: @kordinko: DATA_LENGTH 4000, CHAR_COL_DECL_LENGTH 4000, CHAR_USED C. This is what i get.

Comment: @Milimetric : A.Column1 is nvarchar2(4000). I know the problem is due to that, as i said in description if i SUBSTR the column, it works fine.

Comment: This doesn't necessarily mean the column length is the problem.  It could be other things.  I think it's a bug in the Oracle driver.  I only have a little experience with this, but I found many different versions and the old ones usually had pretty glaring problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to this was to take only half the column length from the oracle side.

If the SQL side column is defined as `NVARCHAR(MAX)`(MAX being 4000), then the maximum length you can import from the Oracle side is half that. So doing `SUBSTR(A.Column1,1,2000)` on the Oracle column becomes necessary!